# Перенаправление с помощью htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть следующая проблема с `.htaccess`: нужно чтобы все запросы страниц уходили в `index.php` (например: `mysite.by` и `mysite.by/register`), но один URI (`mysite.by/любая цифра/любая цифра/набор из цифр и букв`, пример `mysite.by/4/4/ivanov`) надо повесить исключение, чтобы он не направлялся на `index.php` и при этом делался редирект на `mysite.by/htdocs/4/4/ivanov`.
Отправка всех на `index.php` делается просто, но как только я пытаюсь добавить исключение, работает только одно правило.
Вот то, что я сделал

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[A-z0-9]{1,15}$
RewriteRule . /htdocs%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

В случае запроса mysite.by все уходит на index.php как и надо, но как только я пытаюсь вводить, что либо дополнительно, он выполняет первое правило и адрес приобретает вид http://mysi.by/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/4/4/ivanov (при запросе mysi.by/4/4/ivanov)
http://mysi.by/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/htdocs/tt (при запросе mysi.by/tt), хотя такого вида запрос он должен отправлять в index.php

Comment: Приведите фрагмент того что у вас уже есть и не работает. Тогда вам кто-нить поможет. А вообще,обычно сначала делают редирек для частных случаев а потом для всего остального.

Comment: добавил не рабочий код

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[A-z0-9]{1,15}$ тут лишнее отрицание !. Вы все что не соответвует шаблону отпраяляете на htdocs поэтому и циклится.

Comment: когда убрал отрицание, адрес mysute.by/4/4/ivanov направляется на index.php, а должен перенаправляться на mysite.by/htdocs/4/4/ivanov.Но при этом если я напишу адрес mysite.by/htdocs/4/4/ivanov он переходит правильно